# Django serialization error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to serialize my django model like this:

```
>>> from studentapp.models import StudentAcademicPrograms
>>> from studentapp.models import AcademicPrograms, AcademicProgramsManager
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
>>> data = json_serializer.serialize(StudentAcademicPrograms.objects.all())
```

But i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method serialize() must be called with Serializer instance as first argument (got QuerySet instance instead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
serialize('json', StudentAcademicPrograms.objects.all())
```

Your specific problem is that you are try to call `serialize()` on a `Serializer` class, not instance.

```
JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
json_serializer = JSONSerializer()
json_serializer.serialize(StudentAcademicPrograms.objects.all())
data = json_serializer.getvalue()
```

Also check out [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.get_serializer) from django docs.

Comment: Hi i have one small question. How do i write the output to a file so that i can access it using an angularjs service?

Comment: @crozzfire if you want to write it into the file, follow the link I've provided - there is an example there.

Comment: hi alex! a little help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126989/django-making-a-list-of-a-field-grouping-by-another-field-in-model/29128127#29128127

Answer (score 2):

You must instantiate `json_serializer`

```
>>> data = json_serializer().serialize(StudentAcademicPrograms.objects.all())
```

Notice `()` after json_serializer.