# Django making a list of a field grouping by another field in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model called MyModel which has some dummy data as follows:

```
     item    date     value
------------------------------
      ab    8/10/12   124
      ab    7/10/12   433
      ab    6/10/12    99
      abc   8/10/12    23
      abc   7/10/12    80
```

I would like to query this Model in such a way that i get an output as follows:

```
[{'item': 'ab', 'values': [ 124, 433, 99]},
 {'item': 'abc', 'values': [ 23, 80]}]
```

How would i be able to do this using the django ORM?

Comment: You can get items with a distinct query.  Then loop to filter values by item.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**(Apr 4 '16) UPDATE: This is a working solution for Django <= 1.7. For newer versions please read [Creating your own Aggregate Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#creating-your-own-aggregate-functions) from the docs.**

Using a custom `Concat` aggregate taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/ludoo/ca6ed07e5c8017272701) (*[an article about the topic](http://harkablog.com/inside-the-django-orm-aggregates.html)*)

Define this:

```
class Concat(models.Aggregate):
    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        #we send source=CharField to prevent Django from casting string to int
        aggregate = SQLConcat(col, source=models.CharField(), is_summary=is_summary, **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate

#for mysql
class SQLConcat(models.sql.aggregates.Aggregate):
    sql_function = 'group_concat'

    @property
    def sql_template(self):
        if self.extra.get('separator'):
            return '%(function)s(%(field)s SEPARATOR "%(separator)s")'
        else:
            return '%(function)s(%(field)s)'

#For PostgreSQL >= 9.0
#Aways use with separator, e.g. .annotate(values=Concat('value', separator=','))     
class SQLConcat(models.sql.aggregates.Aggregate):
    sql_function = 'string_agg'

    @property
    def sql_template(self):
        #the ::text cast is a hardcoded hack to work with integer columns
        return "%(function)s(%(field)s::text, '%(separator)s')"

#For PostgreSQL >= 8.4 and < 9.0
#Aways use with separator, e.g. .annotate(values=Concat('value', separator=','))     
class SQLConcat(models.sql.aggregates.Aggregate):
    sql_function = 'array_to_string'

    @property
    def sql_template(self):
        return "%(function)s(array_agg(%(field)s), '%(separator)s')"

#For PostgreSQL < 8.4 you should define array_agg before using it:
#CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg (anyelement)
#(
#    sfunc = array_append,
#    stype = anyarray,
#    initcond = '{}'
#);

class MyModel(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

so now you can do:

```
>>> from my_app.models import MyModel, Concat
>>> MyModel.objects.values('item').annotate(values=Concat('value'))
[{'item': u'ab', 'values': u'124,433,99'}, {'item': u'abc', 'values': u'23,80'}]
```

to get `values` as a list of integers you need to manually `.split` and cast to `int`. Something like:

```
>>> my_list = MyModel.objects.values('item').annotate(values=Concat('value'))
>>> for i in my_list:
...     i['values'] = [int(v) for v in i['values'].split(',')]
...
>>> my_list
[{'item': u'ab', 'values': [124, 433, 99]}, {'item': u'abc', 'values': [23, 80]}]
```

Comment: Concat will not append `values`.

Comment: Concat is MySQL [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), it will concat the values into string. I've just tested it. There was just a little bug where django tries to cast that string to int, the fix was to send `source=models.CharField()` in the `add_to_query` method. Full code provided.

Comment: is there a similar one for postgresql?

Comment: i have postgresql 9.3 and i am getting this error:     KeyError: u'separator'

Comment: ok now i got a new programming error:.....  ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...tring_agg("irmsapp_mymodel"."value", ",")) AS "values" ...

Comment: `SEPARATOR` is for MySQL version of `group_concat`, the template for Postgre should be `'%(function)s(%(field)s, "%(separator)s")'`. BTW just for the test you can try a hardcoded version like - `return "string_agg(%(field)s, ',')"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73283/discussion-between-rogerfederer-and-todor).

Comment: hi todor i added a new query in the chat. could you please let me know!

Comment: module has been removed in later django versions `models.sql.aggregates`

Answer (score 2):

In case your Django is backed by PostgreSQL, you can use `extra` in combination with `string_agg`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Assuming the table you posted is a ManyToManyRelation with `item` actually being a reference to your model `MyModel`, with the model table being `mymodel` and the mapping table being `mymodel_value`:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={
    'values':
        """
        SELECT string_agg(value, ', ' ORDER BY value)
          FROM mymodel_value
         WHERE mymodel.id=mymodel_value.item
        """
}).values('values')
```

The resulting dictionary will have an entry `values` with a string as value that is the concatenated (aggregated) list of values for each `item`.

Try this in the Django shell (`./manage.py shell`). You might have to add more tables to the subselect in case those have not been added by the ORM, yet. (The main model table should definitely be there, already.) It depends on how complex the model relations are.

Turn on DB logging to inspect the query that the ORM generates.