# Group records by date and add list of fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    published = models.DateField()
    items_sold = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to group all books by the published date and I want to `SUM` the sold items (`items_sold`). Additionally I want to add a list of all `names` to the output. So my expected output would look like this:

```
[{'date': datetime.date(2015, 12, 14), 'total_sold': 5000, 'names': ['Book A', 'Book B']}, 
 {'date': datetime.date(2016, 11, 4), 'total_sold': 10000, 'names': ['Book C']}, ... ]
```

I tried to solve this using `annotate`:

```
Book.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sold=Sum('items_sold'))
```

But I have no idea how I can get a list of the names into the result. Is `annotate` the right approach here? Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

### EDIT:

Thanks to Todor's comment I found a partly solution using a custom Aggregate:

```
class Concat(models.Aggregate):
    """
    Using SQLite `group_concat` function  
    """
    function = 'group_concat'
    template = '%(function)s(%(field)s, "%(separator)s")'
```

Now I have this query:

```
Book.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sold=Sum('items_sold'), names=Concat('names', separator=',')

> [{'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 5), 'total_sold': 5000, 'names': 'Book A, Book B'}, ...,]
```

The problem now is that the book names are concatenated to a string `names`. I can define a separator, but I don't know how to convert `names` to a list. 
I could do this later using `split` (`names.split(separator)`), but I think this is not save enough as my separator could also be part of the book name. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are on the right path using annotate. In order to add names, check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126989/django-making-a-list-of-a-field-grouping-by-another-field-in-model/29128127#29128127)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not working with django1.9. I get this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'aggregates'`. Maybe this is solvable using `Func()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions). Do you know how?

Comment: Take a look at [Expression API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#expression-api), maybe if you hook on [`convert_value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.convert_value) you would be able to split the string into a list.

Comment: Thanks. I can use `convert_value` to split the list. But `value` is already concatenated at that point. So the problem with a unique separator remains. Any suggestion?

Comment: The concatenation gets applied on DB level, so you will always get concatenated result in python. Just ensure that you are using a separator that won't exists into the results. Inside the `convert_value` I believe you have access to the `separator` `kwarg`, (maybe via `context` kwarg). So you can do `names.split(separator)` as you mention.

Comment: `Just ensure that you are using a separator that won't exists into the results`. Hm, that's the problem. The values are user generated strings.

Comment: Well if you really can't risk using something like `;` for a separator, then do not annotate book names, use `book_ids`, and fetch your book names later.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentioned which database you are using. But Django 1.9 provides certain [postgres specific aggregate functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/) e.g. `ArrayAgg` which will be very useful here:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Book.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sold=Sum('items_sold'), names=ArrayAgg('name'))
```

and, this will aggregate all the names and put them into a list for you.