# group by two values and get the third values

Tags: django, django-orm

I have this Django model with three CharFields, which I want to run a query on to get the existing values for the two of them, and for each combination get the existing values of the third field.

```
    a = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=8000)
    b = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=8000)
    c = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=8000)
```

if assume that these values are in the database:

```
 a  | b  | c  |
---------------
 a1 | b2 | c3 |
 a1 | b2 | c1 |
 a2 | b2 | c3 |
 a1 | b3 | c3 |
 a1 | b2 | c2 |
```

I want some result in this form :

```
{"a1-b2" : [c3, c1, c2], "a2-b2" : [c3], "a1-b3" : [c3]}
or 
{"a1" : {"b2":[c3, c1, c2], "b3": [c3]}, "a2": {"b2" : [c3]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
items = MyModel.objects.annotate(custom_field=Concat('a', Values('-'), 'b').values('custom_field', 'c')
```

**Explanation**

With the part `.annotate(custom_field=Concat('a', Values('-'), 'b')`, you are basically doing a group_by operation in SQL and creating a temporary new column with name `custom_field` in your queryset which will have the value of `a-b`.

This gives you the following structure:

```
a    |    b    |    c    | custom_field
a1        b1        c1          a1-b1
a2        b2        c2          a2-b2 
a1        b1        c3          a1-b1
```

The `.values('custom_field', 'c')` portion fetches only the `custom_field` and `c` columns from this queryset. Now all you have to do is serialize your data.

**EDIT**
If you want your data in that specific format, you can concatenate column `c`. Please read the SO accepted answer in this post. [Django making a list of a field grouping by another field in model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29128127/7183805). You can then create a new field during serialization which will `split()` the concatenated `c` field into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't think of good pure SQL solution, but here's pythonic one using `groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

# Order by key fields so it will be easier to group later
items = YOUR_MODEL.objects.order_by('a', 'b')

# Group items by 'a' and 'b' fields as key
groups = groupby(items, lambda item: (item.a, item.b))

# Create dictionary with values as 'c' field from each item
res = {
    '-'.join(key): list(map(lambda item: item.c, group))
    for key, group in groups
}
# {'a1-b2': ['c3', 'c1', 'c2'], 'a1-b3': ['c3'], 'a2-b2': ['c3']}
```